# Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC

Tags: java, exception, eof, objectinputstream, eofexception

Just trying to read a number. I'm implementing `Serializable` and my `main()` throws an error:

Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1379)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:28)

Here's the code:

```
try ( ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
           FileOutputStream("myFile.dat", true));){ 
           Integer a = 0;   
           output.writeObject(a); 
} 
finally{}; 
try(ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new 
          FileInputStream("myFile.dat")); ){ 
           Integer newNumber = 0; 
           newNumber =  input.readObject(); 
           ++newNumber; 
           System.out.println("This program has been executed " + newNumber
            + " times.");   
          input.close();
}
```

Comment: And what is stored in this file?

Answer (score 0):

The file is empty, or contains fewer than four bytes of actual data after the header, if any.

Comment: So you didn't write the file correctly. Unless you wrote it with `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()/writeUnshared()`, and the object you passed was an `Integer`, your read code won't work as expected. It would be more to the point to use `writeInt()` and `readInt().`

Comment: So you didn't do what I said. You can't mix `writeInt()` and `readObject(),` or the other way around. NB you can't append to files written by `ObjectOutputStream.`

Comment: Tells me nothing. Stack trace and complete exception message is always  required.

Comment: You still haven't fixed it the way I described. Please read everything I've written here again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73891/discussion-between-jcoder-and-ejp).

Comment: This question is still unanswered and too different from the question that is was marked a duplicate of. There are no sockets or anything here, and I am closing all the streams. There is an exception being thrown and no one has said why.

Comment: The question is identical and so is the answer. You are appending a second `ObjectOutputStream` to a stream created by an `ObjectOutputStream.` I said above that you can't do that. The result is two headers in the stream, which both start with `AC`, which is the invalid type code you received, exactly as described in my answer to the duplicated question.